# How to transform a file from Excel format (.xlsx) into a .csv (semicolon) separated values?

Tags: excel, csv, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I'm trying to transform an Excel file into a .csv (semicolon) separated file.

I now that there is a way to transform the file using the function "concatenate" (indeed I used this method) I took me a long time, the file had several columns to transform.

I was thinking to save minutes for the next time I'm trying to see if there is a "faster" way to do this then I tried to save the excel file clicking on:
 "Save As--> Save as Type-->CSV Comma Delimited"

The problem now is that the file (now a CSV)  Since I have values ("Amount" column) delimited by comma (",") I can't just "Replace All "," by ";"

Remember I saved under that format: Comma Delimited (no semicolon as I desired) there is a way to save as type: CSV Semicolon?

Comment: It can be done if you have Excel in one of the languages that saves CSVs with semicolons instead of commas (ex: French). Another way might be to save as tab delimited text and replace the tabs with semicolons in a good text editor

Comment: here's a way that worked in 2013. I'm not on Windows, so I can't test: https://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/save-excel-file-with-any-special-character-delimiter/